# Parse Facebook dialog:andParams causes login screen

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I have been using the Parse Facebook implementation for a while and now I am getting some weird behaviors after updating.

I am logging in a user successfully using

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_about_me",
                   @"user_relationships",@"user_birthday",@"user_location",
                   @"email", nil];

[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissions
                                    block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                            if (!user) {
                                                if (!error) { // The user cancelled the login
                                                    NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                                                } else { // An error occurred
                                                    NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else if (user.isNew) { // Success - a new user was created
                                                NSLog(@"Is New");
                                            }
                                            else { // Success - an existing user logged in
                                                NSLog(@"Existing");
                                            }
                                      }];
```

Which works fine. Now when I want to bring up the post dialog to the user I use

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       @"MY_APP_ID", @"app_id",
                                       caption, @"name",
                                       link, @"link",
                                       description, @"description",
                                       name, @"caption",
                                       picture, @"picture",
                                       nil];
[[PFFacebookUtils facebook] dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Which is bringing up the facebook login popup even though the user is already logged on and is using ios6.0 with the facebook settings configured.

Can anyone help me explain what is happening so that I can avoid the user basically having to sign in more than once just to post?

Comment: Are you asking for the appropriate permissions to post to their wall when you log in? i.e. what is your `permissions` set to?

Comment: I updated with my permissions... From what I have read all around the FB documentation is that to present a dialog you do not need to request any posting permissions since the user is the one to initiate the post.

Comment: Oh ok, I guess that makes sense. It's been a while since I've done that and I'm not familiar with `Parse FB`